Will such a scheme work correctly with ATmega328PB?
I am developing a small on-board computer for my rocket model and now I have designed the ATmega328PB connection to the CH340G and I want to ask if there are any errors in the connection and if there are any suggestions for improving the circuit?

Information about generators:
X1: CSTCE16M0V13C99-R0
X2: CSTCE12M0G15C99-R0

It is much easier to read a schematic and check it for errors if you have connections drawn in and only link things with net labels when doing otherwise would create an indecipherable rats' nest. For example, maybe for some reason you decide to connect XO to VCC. This isn't something an experienced engineer would think to check for, so they'll see XO connected to the crystal, XO connected to the CH340, and completely miss the random XO label on the other side of the schematic connected to VCC.

Using a program that will allow you to highlight or hide entire net on the schematic and PCB would help in detecting the missing Vcc-+5V connection. Unfortunately, because you've connected the +5V to more than one place the EDA program won't necessarily automatically detect it- it just 'sees' two independent nets.

Please post a part number for the crystal.

@ScottSeidman The microcontroller crystal is numbered X1, and for the CH340G it is numbered X2

That's not quite what I'm looking for.  Microcontrollers can be picky about what "works" to build an oscillator.  You have selected some sort of package with built in caps, which may be fine, but I'd like to know the value of the caps.  If you'd like somebody to verify your choice was correct, you need to let people know exactly what X1 and X2 are.

@ScottSeidman Do you mean that it is worth writing the frequency of the generator?

No.  that's already there.  I mean when you go to buy the part to populate your board, what part do you intend to buy?

@ScottSeidman Oh, I know what you mean, I'm going to edit the question now

Firstly, I suggest working on your diagram.  A hard-to-read diagram will almost inevitably have mistakes.
Specifically about the circuit:

Where are the decoupling caps?
How does VCC relate to +5V?
Do you need two crystals? (Or any?).
Do you need the /RST switch on the board?
Consider an extra general-purpose LED
(EDIT) Make sure you read the issues in the other answer which I didn't see: without fixing /RST you'll never program it through the ISP.

For a rocket, I'll guess weight is important and perhaps cost if some get unexpected hard landings.
Crystals Perhaps you could get rid of the crystals and change to CH340E, omits some pins you don't use, and has built-in crystal.  This CPU 328PB also has a built-in oscillator much more accurate than non-B part, perfectly good for async comms.  Together that might take some weight and power down.
Switch Consider a switch on an ISP cable, as you surely only need the reset switch during debugging.
General Purpose LED It's often extremely useful to have an LED you can blink just to check basic functionality.  Embedded boards can be tricky to debug, and showing the current state is running is extremely helpful.  (Eg, a single letter in Morse code or even 300 bit/sec serial gives good "characteristic flashing" showing you everything is functioning correctly.)
Back to the diagram...

Your diagram is very cramped in the exact areas you need to check most, with lines overlapping text and so on.  (Eg areas near U1.29, U1.20, U8.1-4).
Use logical-layout symbols (pins grouped by function) not physical (grouped by pin numbers).
If you're using named-signals, use the input-output arrows to make sure they go the right way.
Name your signals for the use in this circuit; especially important for the very many functions for MPU pins.
It's very easy to get TX and RX swapped, each chip tends to name them for the direction out/in to that chip; but RS-232 convention is "DTE-centric" which doesn't make sense for a lot of modern devices.  So names like CPU_RXD are helpful: this is an input to the CPU.
Many prefer the Inputs on the left and the outputs on the right; thus the connector is left most, then the interface chip.  Typically the CPU is in the middle, and output devices on the right.
Positive is always up, negative is always down.
Correct designators: "U2" appears to be a connector and so should be "J"; it appears to be an AVR ISP connector, good to label it as such.

A portion of the diagram might therefore look better like this:

There is a wealth of good advice at the EE.SE sticky answer about diagrams.

Thank you for such a detailed answer! I use an external crystal for how much computing power is still required to process flight data, so I'm afraid that the internal generator will not be enough for these purposes

It is worth working on the readability of the scheme. I have been doing this recently and do not have such experience, but I will take into account all your wishes) and the rest of the connection diagram is correct?

"rest of the connection diagram is correct?"  It's hard to tell, that's why my suggestion is to redraw it.  Per my answer, you must have decoupling caps and check datasheets carefully for instructions on this (eg CH340 say V3 cap should be 0.1μF) and if +5V isn't connected then U8 has no power.

You might think about changing from EasyEDA.  It's a good program to start with, but  because it's online it really discourages the kind of editing effort that a good diagram (and in due course, a good PCB) requires.  Putting effort into learning how to use one of the better tools is really time well spent and will save you endless hours.  Many find that open-source KiCad suits their needs for interactivity, platform independence, quality, libraries etc, and certainly more than adequate for a board like you're describing.

OK, thanks for the advice! I will try to use KiCad to work with the wiring of the boards

@DYNAMICAEROSPACE Why are you even using an old 8-bitter if computing power is a priority? In case you need to do things like floating point arithmetic then AVR is entirely unsuitable.

@Lundin I meant that the computing power of the ATmega328PB with a frequency of 16 MHz is quite enough, but I'm afraid that at 8 MHz they will no longer be enough

@Lundin The microcontroller will not do calculations, but only send telemetry to Earth and issue signals for the correct activation of rescue systems

The accepted answer provides general suggestions on styling and common norms on PCB design but never point out the mistakes on the schematic. I see at least two mistakes.

CC1 and CC2 on Type C USB connector IS NOT D+ and D-, and therefore should not connect to UD+ and UD-. CC1 and CC2 each should be terminated with a 5.1k to the GND so that 5V can be correctly sourced via VBUS. The symbol that you are using on EasyEDA lack of D+/D- suggesting that you are picking a part that is designed for USB charger instead of USB communication. Search for a Type C connector symbol that has the D+/D- pins.



RST label near the SW1 is wrongly connected to the GND, it should be connected to pin 29 of the MCU (PC6/RESET#).

One more general note, I don't know how much you know the differences between ATmega328P (used in Arduino Uno/Nano/Pro Mini) from ATmega328PB that you use. If you are intend to use Arduino framework to program it, the classic Arduino framework provided by Arduino organization will not support 328PB (i.e. you can't use it as an Arduino Uno), you will have to install third party Arduino Core (e.g. MCUDude's MiniCore to get the support for 328PB.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I got it, thanks for such a detailed answer, I'll fix the errors in the circuit and look at the microcontroller
